# How to change an SQL query to either HQL or Criteria?

Tags: hibernate, hql, criteria

I have the following tables....

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Emp_PersonalDetails {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="EMPID")
private int id;
private String firstName;
private String middleName;
private String lastName;
private String driversLicenseNo;
private String passportNo;
@Column(columnDefinition="DATE")
private Date pportLicenseExp;
private String gender;;
private String nationality;
private String maritalStatus;
@Column(columnDefinition="DATE")
private Date dob;
@Column(columnDefinition="mediumblob")
byte[] image;
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "details", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)  
private Emp_JobDetails jobDetails;
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "details", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)  
private Emp_Reporting reportingDetails;
```

\contrutor + getters & setters

and another...

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Emp_JobDetails {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "EJDID")
private int id;
private String jobTitle;
private String department;
private String status;
private String category;
private Date startDate;
private Date endDate;
private String location;
private Date joinedDate;
@Column(length=1000)
private String otherDetails;
@OneToOne
private Emp_PersonalDetails details;
```

\contrutor + getters & setters
and finally...

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Emp_Reporting {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "RDID")
private int id;
private String manager;
private String reportingMethod;
private Date prDate;
private Date nextPrDate;
private String level;
@Column(length=1000)
private String comments;
@OneToOne
```

//  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Emp_PersonalDetails details;

here is the SQL query that is working fine but is just too long winded. How can I change this to an HQL or Criteria based query? Thanks

```
SELECT EMPP.empid, EMPP.firstName, EMPP.middleName, EMPP.lastName, EMPJ.jobTitle, 
       EMPJ.status, EMPJ.department, EMPR.manager 
FROM   Emp_PersonalDetails EMPP 
JOIN   Emp_JobDetails EMPJ 
ON     EMPP.EMPID = EMPJ.EJDID 
JOIN   Emp_Reporting EMPR 
ON     EMPP.EMPID = EMPR.RDID 
WHERE  EMPP.firstName LIKE :name 
OR     EMPP.empid LIKE:id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do a select from `Emp_Reporting` table :)

```
SELECT EMPP.empid, [ommited for formatting ...] 
FROM Emp_Reporting EMPR 
         inner join EMPR.details EMPP
         inner join EMPP.jobDetails EMPJ 
WHERE EMPP.firstName LIKE :name OR EMPP.id= :id
```

---

```
ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
projectionList.add(Projections.property("EMPP.id"));
projectionList.add(Projections.property("EMPP.firstName"));
projectionList.add(Projections.property("..."));
Criteria criteria = createCriteria(Emp_Reporting.class,"EMPR")
        .createAlias("details","EMPP")
        .createAlias("EMPP.jobDetails","EMPJ")
        .setProjection(projectionList)
        .add(Restrictions.eq("EMPP.firstName", value))
        .add(Restrictions.eq("EMPP.id", value));
```

Comment: I'm this did not work. org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'null.details'

Comment: What hibernate version you're using?

Comment: Version hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final

Comment: I can't see a problem with the hql syntax. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#d5e2836

Can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: This is the actual error I'm getting. There was a slight error in the syntax before:  Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: empid of: org.charles.periodic.metals.beans.Emp_PersonalDetails

Comment: that's right, my bad, it should be id. not empid, at the where statement

Comment: Thanks, it works now. How about using the Criteria API? Just to finish my learning. Many thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for this Andre. The documentation is a bit hard to understand when you are new to this. I'm now using the Criteria solution.